# Selenium returning "NoSuchElementException" ONLY when run from the AWS lambda function (and despite valid path)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a bit of trouble running my lambda function on AWS. It worked previously, but I had to change some details in my terraform build, and the function stopped working after this (whether just by some coincidence or not). Whenever I run it, **I'm getting a "NoSuchElementException" from Selenium**. I'm trying to locate an element by the XPath.

**The XPath is valid**. If I run the function locally, it works perfectly fine and can locate the element. I have also verified that my function is being passed the information it needs. The code that is trying to locate this element is below:

```
    def getElementText(website, driver):
        try:
            # Open website
            driver.get(website.link)
            time.sleep(10)
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(website.elementPath)
            website.elementText = element.text
            time.sleep(10)
            logging.info("Element text: " + str(website.elementText))
            return website.elementText
        except NoSuchElementException as error:
            logging.error(error)
            raise ValueError("There was a problem finding the element by the xpath on the " + website.name + " website. ", error)
        except Exception as error:
            logging.error(error)
            raise ValueError("There may be a problem with the " + website.name + " website link. ", error)
```

I have searched for solutions online, and **I did come across the suggestion to add a wait condition, which I tried**:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, website.elementPath)))
```

I also tried increasing the wait time. When I try this, my function simply times out. It still cannot find the element. I wanted to try locating the element by some way other than the XPath, but **it doesn't have a class name, ID, etc**. It's simply text in a paragraph (on a page that I do not manage). I also tried changing the above to "element_to_be_clickable", however, I'm pretty sure that's wrong anyway, as the element isn't supposed to be clickable like a button.

I tried doing something similar to what's shown for explicit waits on the Selenium documentation page as well: https://www.selenium.dev/nl/documentation/webdriver/waits/ Their example is the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
def document_initialised(driver):
    return driver.execute_script("return initialised")

driver.navigate("file:///race_condition.html")
WebDriverWait(driver).until(document_initialised)
el = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
assert el.text == "Hello from JavaScript!"
```

I didn't/don't really think the terraform changes are relevant because all I did was change its access to SSM parameters and add some policies around that, which is for one of my other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If the website which you are testing using selenium is having a responsive

behaviour check the XPath for various browser dimensions and resolutions, aws

lambda might open up chrome with different dimensions than your local system